# How to place a patch in a top plate?

Tags: framing

I need to replace about six feet of top plate. I will cut out the rotten section and insert new wood. What only makes sense to me is to center the cut over the stud so that the ends of the old and new have support. This means only 3/4" of stud support each end. See sketch. Is this correct? There will be a second plate atop the first and that I can overlap by a couple feet.

[image]

Comment: That is the way it is usually done.  Can also sister the stud, so you have more bearing surface.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the butt joint over a stud. You just need to stagger the butt joints in the dual top plates by 2'-0" or more. [IRC R602.3.2](https://codes.iccsafe.org/content/IRC2021P2/chapter-6-wall-construction#IRC2021P2_Pt03_Ch06_SecR602.3.2):

> Wood stud walls shall be capped with a double top plate installed to provide overlapping at corners and intersections with bearing partitions. End joints in top plates shall be offset not less than 24 inches (610 mm). Joints in plates need not occur over studs. Plates shall be not less than 2-inches (51 mm) nominal thickness and have a width not less than the width of the studs.

Follow the link to see exceptions if doing the staggered joints is difficult. If each rafter is centered pretty well above a corresponding stud, then you can instead (probably) install a light gauge steel plate if that's easier. See the exceptions if this alternative sounds attractive.

For staggered top plates, see item 14 from the Table R602.3(1) nail schedule below [IRC R602.3](https://codes.iccsafe.org/content/IRC2021P2/chapter-6-wall-construction#IRC2021P2_Pt03_Ch06_SecR602.3).

The reason for the staggered joints is so that the top plate can resist significant tension forces as part of the house's wind and earthquake resistance. See https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bJAJ4gB039k&t=264s if you care to know more. Just a minute or two, not the whole thing, although feel free to watch the whole thing.